# WordPress: category_description filters <br /> and href-attributes

Tags: wordpress

If I put `<br />` tag or some href-attribues like `rel="nofollow"` or `target="_blank"` in the category description and save the category, these changes are lost...

I looks like wordpress is filtern this code types in the category description...

anybody an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WordPress strips away the HTML functionality in category description. If you need to allow html tag in category description you need to add some code in your theme functions.php file

```
foreach ( array( 'pre_term_description' ) as $filter ) {
  remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_filter_kses' );
}
foreach ( array( 'term_description' ) as $filter ) {
  remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_kses_data' );
}
```

Comment: Okay Great  :-) :-)

Comment: This no longer works